# What type of statistical analysis should I use?

Tags: methodology

I have collected data for 30 patients for a certain test. This test was administered at 6 different but consistent intervals, and each test for each patient has lots of variables. If I want to do an analysis that compares both the differences among the intervals AND between the patients at the intervals, what sort of statistical methods are recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a multilevel modeling approach would be useful for you. Check out this tutorial by [Woltman et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.20982/tqmp.08.1.p052) or this introduction by [Snijders](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00170145.pdf).

Multilevel models in a longitudinal framework allow you to describe differences within individuals (level 1) and between individuals (level 2).